# Get data from balise html in twig symfony with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, symfony

I work for an Ecommerce project with symfony,javascript and jquery. I like to get data from HTML Balise for the current product:

**HTML**

```
 {% for  p in products %}
  <a id="#basket-modal" data-url={{ path('ajout_prod_panier', {'id': p.id}) }}" href="#" data-id="{{ p.id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="basket-modal" class="basket-modal btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Ajouter au panier</a>
 {% endfor %}
```

**Script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".basket-modal").on({ click: function() {
      var op_prod_id = $(".basket-modal").data('id');
      console.log(op_prod_id);
     }
  });
 });
</script>
```

In my case I have two products, but the problem is that when I click on one of the two button that refer to the products, the id of the first product is always displayed , it's not dynamic !! 
Someone can help me please ?

Comment: it's because they all have the same classe `.basket-modal` so it take the first element.

Comment: so what can I do !

Comment: a minimum of research and you'd have found `$(this)`

Comment: ah thanks @t-n-y u are right